# How do I setup and utilize Shoulda, Factory_Girl, and Cucumber in a Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, shoulda, factory-bot

I'm able to get my Gemfile how I like it:

```
# Gemfile
source "http://gemcutter.org"
gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git"
git "git://github.com/rails/arel.git"
git "git://github.com/rails/rack.git"
gem "sqlite3-ruby"

group :test do
  gem "shoulda",      :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda.git",      :branch => "rails3"
  gem "factory_girl", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl.git", :branch => "rails3"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "cucumber-rails"
end
```

Then, of course, `bundle install`

From here, would someone be able to walk me through the process of generating a Cucumber scenario, creating a Factory, and then using the factory with Shoulda declarations inside a unit test? I've seen bits and pieces of all of these things scattered over blogs but due to the speed at which Rails3 is moving I am having a hard time finding a definitive source and my own forays have been unsuccessful and frustrating. Rather than providing my error messages I was hoping someone could just walk me through a clean-slate approach to show how it all works. This would probably be a good addition to http://guides.rails.info Testing section.

Perhaps the resource could be: `bundle exec rails generate scaffold task description:string notes:text project_id:integer due:date complete:boolean` only using Cucumber of course.

Thank you so much on behalf of all of us still learning and trying to follow tdd/bdd!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but last I checked (the first Rails3 beta), Shoulda and Factory Girl weren't compatible with Rails 3. Even the rails3 branches. For example the rails3 branch of FG was last updated in January. There is a "fixes_for_rails3" branch that looks more promising.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I was just going crazy because I was sure I had set everything up correctly.

Comment: Ahh, this site says neither is yet working: http://www.railsplugins.org/plugins/27-shoulda | http://www.railsplugins.org/plugins/208-factory-girl ...but, it's also touched on here: http://darwinweb.net/articles/82 --has anyone tried these?